# How to count comparisons in selection and insertion sorts?

Tags: java, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I am writing 2 different sorts, one being selection the other being insertion. The following is my insertion sort method

```
public static void  iSort(String[] array)
{
  int i, j, k;
  String temp; 
  for(i = 1; i<array.length; i++)
  {
   k=i;
   for(j = k-1; j>=0 && array[j].compareTo(array[k])>0; j--)
   {
    ccounter++;
     temp = array[j];
     array[j] = array[k];
     array[k] = temp;
     k--;
   }
   }
 }
```

where ccounter is a static class variable. When I test this using a 1000 element array of strings, i get a value of 239507. However, when I test with a correctly ordered array of strings, I get a value of zero, which I know is incorrect as the best case performance is n comparisons for n terms. I wonder if my method is written incorrectly, or if the counter is placed incorrectly

Comment: you are counting swaps, not comparisons. (i.e. you are not counting comparison that result in `<=0`)

Comment: In the inner for loop, move the comparison inside the for loop. Currently you count only when you need to swap. If the comparison is done inside the loop you will count all the comparisons made.

Comment: @arunmoezhi By this do you mean take the condition from the loop parentheses and place them in the actual body of the loop?

Comment: Yes. Place it inside the loop body after the counter increment.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, I just realized that, thanks for bringing it to my attention. What you say makes total sense, can't believe I missed it.

Comment: @arunmoezhi Thanks a lot that helped. However, when I do best case (everything in order), it should give me n comparisons right? It doesn't give me that, and I'm starting to think I wrote the sort incorrectly

Comment: For the best case your inner loop should be executed once for every iteration of the outer loop. Are you breaking from the inner loop if you find the new element to be already in the sorted order?

Comment: @arunmoezhi I made some fixes, and got it working! Thanks a lot. I wish I could rep you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, if you exit the loop because `compareTo()` has returned `false`, you are not counting that final comparison.

If I were writing this, I'd wrap the comparison code in a function that would call `compareTo()` and increment the counter. I would then use this wrapper function exclusively, to do all the comparisons. This way there's no chance of miscounting.

Answer (score 0):

increment counter for every execution of inner loop and do the comparison after incrementing the counter

```
public static void  iSort(String[] array)
{
  int i, j, k,ccounter=0;
  String temp; 
  for(i = 1; i<array.length; i++)
  {
        k=i;
        for(j = k-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
                 ccounter++; //increment counter for every execution of inner loop
                 //better to do integer comparison than string comparison
                 if(Integer.parseInt(array[j]) <= Integer.parseInt(array[k]))
                 {
                     break;
                 }
                 temp = array[j];
                 array[j] = array[k];
                 array[k] = temp;
                 k--;
        }
   }
}
```